# REGEXP_SUBSTR is inconsistent with extracting digits before a comma/decimal point

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

my regex looks like this:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(my_column,'[^,]+',1,1) from myTable;
```

this returns the results just fine:

| regex | value |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 11,2 |
| 5 | 5,2 |
| 11 | 11,4 |
| 6 | 6,6 |

however when a value starts with a 0 its returns the following

| regex | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0,1 |

How can I select the 0 instead of the 1?

Comment: can you always add data and tables and produce a [mre]

Comment: you could use this pattern (meaning all digits before a ,) `\d+(?=,)`

Comment: @VvdL Oracle does not support look-ahead in its regular expression syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had a string with `'0,1'` your query would return `0`, not `1`.

What you're seeing suggests your column is actually a number rather than a string, your NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS setting has a comma as the decimal separator, and you using implicit conversion to convert the number to a string then applying your regular expression to that.

So rather than doing any string manipulation, just truncate the values to get the integer part:

```
select TRUNC(my_column) from myTable;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=11a3382de8ab689766107edbf02d3fc3)

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the *leading* digits before the comma, you should be using `^[^,]+`:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(my_column, '^[^,]+', 1, 1) FROM myTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need regular expressions here? It seems you want to return values that precede comma character. So, if all values follow the same pattern you posted in sample data, then `substr + instr` do the job:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '11,2' from dual union all
  3     select '5,2'  from dual union all
  4     select '11,4' from dual union all
  5     select '6,6'  from dual union all
  6     select '0,1'  from dual
  7    )
```

Query begins here:

```
  8  select col, substr(col, 1, instr(col, ',') - 1) result
  9  from test;

COL  RESU
---- ----
11,2 11
5,2  5
11,4 11
6,6  6
0,1  0

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your values are supposed to represent numbers, you can just use `TRUNC` as long as your numeric separated characters are set properly for your session.

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ", ";

WITH
    sample_data (my_column)
    AS
        (SELECT TO_NUMBER ('11,2') FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT TO_NUMBER ('5,2') FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT TO_NUMBER ('11,4') FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT TO_NUMBER ('6,6') FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT TO_NUMBER ('0,1') FROM DUAL)
SELECT trunc(my_column)
  FROM sample_data;
```